# Return Value from weblink

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get the balance value from this XML;

```
<eveapi version="2"><currentTime>2015-10-07 07:11:13</currentTime>
<result>
 <rowset name="accounts" key="accountID" columns="accountID,accountKey,balance">
 <row accountID="68743742" accountKey="1000" balance="67964604.15"/> 
 </rowset>
 </result> 
  <cachedUntil>2015-10-07 07:26:13</cachedUntil>
 </eveapi>
```

here is what I've tried;

```
public void LoadBox1()
{
    string URL = "https://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH";
    XElement elements = XElement.Load(URL);
    txtBALANCE.Text = new XElement("eveapi", (from c in elements.Elements("result") select new XElement("result", c.Element("balance"))).Take(1)).Value;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadBox1();
}
```

I'm taking a wild guess at this ... is it because the value i want is a attribute of row?

RESOLVED

here is how i did it:

```
        public void LoadBox1()
    {
        string URL = "https://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH";
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(URL);
        XmlNodeList ndlist = xdoc.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row");
        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in ndlist)
        {
            if (xmlnode.Attributes["balance"] != null) ;
                txtBALANCE.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["balance"].InnerText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your question ?

Comment: can't really make it anymore simple then what i've wrote, i simple want to get the balance ammount and put it in txtbox?

Comment: It must be`...select new XElement("row", c.Element("balance"))).Take(1)).Value;`

Comment: tried and didnt populate the text box

Comment: also doesn't work. it does give me red lines when switching Value & take around.

Comment: Follow this order in you _XElement_ and use _XAttribute_ for **balance** `var balance = xdoc.Element("eveapi").Element("result").Element("rowset").Element("row").Attribute("balance").Value;`

Comment: where am i sticking this? am i replacing the whole last line?

Comment: still struggeling can't seem to call it correctly =[

Comment: See my updated answer., It will work :)

Comment: Please post your answer separately, not as part of the question.

Comment: i did that once and was told not to do that >.>

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 txtBALANCE.Text =elements.Element("eveapi").Element("result").Element("rowset").Element("row").Attribute("balance").Value;
```

Comment: still nope. the error im getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in No-IdeaV2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Losec Could you post complete XML you are having in `elements` - XElement

Comment: what's in my answer is what im working from, thats the XML i get from my link.